# Authenticate to AWS EKS rest API

Tags: kubectl, amazon-eks

From the documentation it looks like I can attain a token for a cluster to query EKS REST API, and I've got the token in this format : k8s-aws-v1.aHR0cHM6Ly9zdHMuYXAtc291dGgtMS5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29......

But when I try to use this token in Postman against the endpoint https://APISERVER/clusters?maxResults=5&nextToken=nextToken HTTP/1.1

I get the following

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmO1y.png)

Looks like I'm missing some permissions here, how do I assign them?

Another question I have I can't seem to run kubectl commands on AWS cloud shell? (could do it on other clouds)

Thanks